# Django slice template tag not working with negative indices

Tags: python, django, list, django-templates

I have a list of 2 dicts

```
foobar = [ {dict1},
        {dict2}
      ]
```

Django's docs say that the slice template tag works EXACTLY like python slice.

So I tested in a python shell, and sure enough:

```
>>> foo = [1,2]
>>> foo[-2]
1
```

However, when I do this in my template:

```
{% with foobar|slice:"-2" as previous_thing %}
{{ previous_thing }}
```

I get an empty list `[]`.

`{% with foobar|slice:"1" as previous_thing %}` yields what I expect (the first item in the list), as does `{{ foobar }}` (a list of 2 dicts).

What the heck is going on?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> foo = [1,2]
```

This is called indexing:

```
>>> foo[-2]
1
```

and [this is called slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/the-python-slice-notation):

```
>>> foo[:-2]  #return all items up to -2 index(i.e 0th index), so empty list
[]
>>> foo[:-1]
[1]
>>> foo[:2]
[1, 2]
```

Slicing works for non-existent indexes as well:

```
>>> foo[-10000:100000]
[1, 2]
```

But indexing won't:

```
>>> foo[100000]
Traceback (most recent call last):
    foo[100000]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: True, but again `slice:"1"` works. So my question remains open.

Comment: @Colleen What do you mean? `slice:"1"` works because `[1, 2][:1]` returns `[1]` while:     `[1, 2][1]` would return `2`.

Comment: 'slice:"1" works because [1, 2][:1]' is what I was looking for. Roughly. (Aka, if you pass an index to the slice template tag, it's going to assume you mean `:index`. (Edit, ahem, duh, exclusive).

Comment: @Colleen There's nothing wrong with `foo[:-2]`, it is equivalent to: `foo[:0]`, return all items up to 0th index(not inclusive), as there are no items before 0th index so it returns empty list.

Comment: lol yeah realized the dumb and made the edit as you were typing :P